# Turn off Word Suggestion with Inputscope="Search"

Tags: windows-phone-7, autocomplete, autosuggest, inputscope

I have a Search Box which is an AutoComplete box In my view having word suggestions with auto complete box makes no sense and occupies additional screen space, but I like Search keyboard layout,

so help me to turn of word suggestion with inputscope search or help me to make the same keyboard layout by any mean.

Thanks

=================

## **Update**

Currently I have changed InputScope to URL it gives almost same keyboard layout with no suggestion but only ".com" giving me a bad look.

Comment: I was looking for the same thing. I prefer the big black on white 'next' or 'continue' arrow instead of a misleading carriage return, but also want to turn suggestions off. Looks like a choice between Auto-suggest and a slightly out of place'.com' button.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try "Default"? Implied from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426929%28VS.95%29.aspx

- **Default** - Default, and other standard input scope values
- **Text** - Standard layout with features such as autocorrect and text suggestion

Which implies to me that you'll only get autocorrect if you set it to text.

Comment: I'm not sure the info in that link is entirely accurate. 'Search' is not semi-transparent (that I can see), and definitely has suggestions. This page seems more accurate http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh393998(v=vs.105).aspx